# Fitting a GARCH BEKK model

Tags: volatility, garch

I am trying to find whether there is significant volatility transmission between two price series (t=1000). A literature review learned me that the GARCH BEKK model is suitable for this.

The SAS package can estimate it, see [user guide](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/etsug/63939/HTML/default/viewer.htm#etsug_varmax_sect037.htm)
However, I am getting strange results. Now I am in doubt about whether I am doing this the right way. I thought I should just make sure the series are stationary by first differencing them and afterwards, I can directly put them into the GARCH BEKK model by SAS.

Like this:

```
proc varmax data=price-series;
model series1 series2; 
garch q=1 p=1 form=bekk;
run;
```

Which steps am I overlooking?

Answer (score 2):

should be price returns, transforming your series as return=ln(Pt/Pt-1), in words, it means the natural logarithmic transformation of the ratio of price at time t to price at time t-1